# I want my view split 46:54 into 2 views, proportioned to phone screen. Views have subviews. How?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want my main view to be separated into two views, where left takes 46% and right takes 54% of screen, minus a pixel for a divider view.

Within these 2 views I want to put some subviews on the storyboard.  Problem is I can't set width constraints of the 2 views since their widths are not calculated until run time, and I believe this constraint ambiguity is why their subviews wont respect constraints I give them (ie: center horizontal).

How can I achieve the results I want?  This is how I am currently setting geometry of the 2 views:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setGeometry()
    }

    func setGeometry(){
        let width = view.bounds.width
        let dividerPoint = width * 0.46
        let height = view.bounds.height
        leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dividerPoint, height: height)
        divider.frame = CGRect(x: dividerPoint, y: 0, width: 1, height: height)
        rightView.frame = CGRect(x: dividerPoint + 1, y: 0, width: width - 1 - dividerPoint, height: height)
    }
```

Comment: you can do it in Interface Builder by constraints. You can don't add divider. Set background color for main view and it will be divider.

Comment: I upvoted Igor's solution, but my question is why are you mixing frames (your code with the main views) with constraints (your question with each section's subviews)? You probably are better off with being consistent all the way through the view hierarchy.

Comment: @maxwellsandstein, if you use constraints, you can change frame with effect only in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. But in this case subviews wouldn't adjust themself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in Interface Builder by constraints. Add equal width constraints from each view to main view with multiplier 0.46 and 0.54 (last also with -1 value).